# How do you use a multi variable constructor in a linked list?

Tags: java, constructor, linked-list

I have been trying to figure out how to replace the "data" variable in a linked list with a constructor class that I have made. I am new to programming and I can't figure out the equivalent of countryInfo[0].countryName = Germany for a linked list. I know there is a class out there that makes this easy but my assignment is to create a linked list class to use so that we know the workings in case I am using a language that doesn't already have a linked list method to work with. My Constructor is:

```
public class Countries {
     public String countryName;
     public String latitude;
     public String longitude;
     public int countryArea;
     public int countryPopulation;
     public double countryGDP;
     public int countryYear;
}
```

My idea is to have one Node with each of these variables in that node with a next leading to the next node of variables until the end. Every tutorial that I have viewed so far has

```
public dataType data;
public Node<dataType> next;
```

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: All collection implements `iterator()`, so not really need to implement linked lists...

Comment: There is no such thing as a "constructor class". All classes have one or more constructors. If you don't write one yourself, a default one is created by the compiler. *(for the funny people: this is not about the `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` class)*